# How to render in template in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to display my data on the HTML file but I am unable to display, I have a `function` in `views.py` file and i render this function data on my HTML file, but it's not going to the HTML path, please let me know how I can display data in Django default template.

Here is my app `appname` and its have a `views.py` file and this file has a function that displays my data on the HTML page...
please have a look at the `views.py` file...

```
def mydata():
   var1=Mymodel.objects.all()
   template_name='../templates/admin/appname/modelname/change_list.html'
   context={'var1':var1}
   return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Note: this template folder is that which Django provides in default, it's not available inside my app (`appname`), it's available outside of my app

so main issue is in thsi path `template_name='../templates/admin/appname/modelname/change_list.html'`, because it's getting the correct path

Answer (score 1):

Create folder `templates` inside you app, put there `template.html`. Then in views.py:

```
def mydata(request):

    you code

    return render(request, 'template.html', locals())
```

`locals` will collect all variables that you created inside function.

Comment: @saini tor this will by default template folder for app